# etiqueta windowsforms deberia ser sinonimo de winforms

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

Revisando las etiquetas vi que existe [winforms](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms) y [windowsforms](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowsforms), sugiero que se conviertan en sinonimos. Dado a que implican el mismo tema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He renombrado [windowsforms](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowsforms) a [windows-forms](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-forms) y he hecho que [winforms](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms) sea un sinónimo. La correspondiente descripción de etiqueta se mantiene.

Comment: Y tras ver gracias a @CarlosMuñoz que en el sitio en inglés winforms es la etiqueta principal, estoy intentando cambiarlo para que sea igual pero me da un error.

Comment: Habla con Juan, el pudo hacer algo parecido con la etiqueta nosql. No es toy seguro pero creo que había que borrar las dos etiquetas antes de poder recrearlas

Answer (score 5):

Sugiero que el término [winforms](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms) sea el principal de igual manera que [SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/winforms/info):

Acá pueden ver [todos los sinónimos](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/winforms/synonyms) de [winforms](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms) en inglés

Comment: Eso es precisamente lo que dije, aunque de manera implicita